# PHP Merge Multidimensional Array become one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got this array

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "monday_open" => "10:00:00"
    "monday_close" => "20:00:00"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "tuesday_open" => "00:00:00"
    "tuesday_close" => "00:00:00"
  ]
]
```

How can i combine them become:

```
array:4 [
  "monday_open" => "10:00:00"
  "monday_close" => "20:00:00"
  "tuesday_open" => "00:00:00"
  "tuesday_close" => "00:00:00"
]
```

I've tried using array_walk_recrusive but it doesn't return me with key name:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($v) use (&$arrayFlat) {
            $arrayFlat[] = $v;
        });
```

I've tried this one too but got the same result as array_walk_recrusive:

```
 iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)), 0)
```

Result:

```
array:4 [
  0 => "10:00:00"
  1 => "20:00:00"
  2 => "00:00:00"
  3 => "00:00:00"
]
```

Is there any other way to keep the key value?

Comment: have you tried the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add key param to the closure of the `array_walk_recursive` like this

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($v, $k) use (&$arrayFlat) {
        $arrayFlat[$k] = $v;
    });
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$source_array    =   array(array("monday_open"=>"10:00:00", "monday_close" => "20:00:00"), array("tuesday_open" => "00:00:00", "tuesday_close" => "00:00:00"));
$my_array        =   array();
foreach($source_array as $source){
    foreach($source as $key=> $val){
        $my_array[$key] = $val;
    }
}
print_r($my_array);
```

Comment: Yours work perfect!. Thanks. But i like above answer. much cleaner. 

Thanks!